# How to use options in bash for skipping parts of code

Tags: bash, if-statement, getopts

I have bash script and I want to be able to skip over (that is - do not execute) some of its commands based on options passed while invoking script.

To illustrate what I want to accomplish, I have written script with `if` statements that basically accomplish same thing.

```
if [ "$1" != "skipA" ]
    then
    echo "A"
fi

if [ "$1" != "skipB" ]
    then
    echo "B"
fi

if [ "$1" != "skipC" ]
    then
    echo "C"
fi

if [ "$1" != "skipD" ]
    then
    echo "D"
fi
```

When no arguments are passed while invoking script, all four `echo` statements are executed. If I want to skip one of those echo statements, I use `skipLETTER` as first argument:

```
./script.sh skipA
```

and all letters except `A` are printed. It works, but it does have many limitations - for one, I can not skip many parts using same argument (`$1`). I want to achieve same thing with options, so I can type something like:

```
./script -skipA -skipD
```

and as a result print only `B` and `C` letters.

I know I can use `getopt` or `getopts` to achieve this, but I can not find any simple usage example which achieves what I have described.

Comment: may be you can put `continue` in your if statement in order to skip the first argument..good?

Answer (score 0):

I use a code with the following algorithm:

1. Capture all executable codes in a function in file1
2. Call each function in the sequence as per the logic in file2
3. While calling file2, each and every call will be limited to one liners and name them as steps
4. Call file2 with an option for skipping
5. Have a if statement to read the lines as step and check the current step is less than required step, if yes continue to next step. else use eval to act on it.

Comment: Thanks for tip, but what you have described is actually a lot more complex than using simple ``if`` statement as shown in question (at least as far as I understand it) - since step 4 is what I do (though there is only one file) and have same limitation (only one argument). I asked for solution with options since it should be easier to use than what I have now.

Comment: In this approach, you can have a restart from where it failed. :) file1 acts more like a library (Its not complex when you build and actually its modularity)

Answer (score 0):

POSIX-standard getopts cannot do long options, only single-character ones, so you can't use it for the exact interface outlined in the question.

as an aside, long options should be introduced with two dashes, not one, otherwise there's no way to tell, without knowing the details of the utility, if -skipA is a single option (with a possible optarg), or five single-character options bundled (`-x -y` is the same as `-xy`, both are different from `--xy`).

going forward with portable code ([getopts spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html)) and choosing `s` for the *skip* option, here's a short example:

```
#!/bin/sh

contains()
{
  case "$1" in
  *$2*) return 0 ;;
  esac
  return 1
}

requested()
{
  ! contains "$skip" "$1"
}

while getopts s: optname; do
  case $optname in
  s) skip="$OPTARG" ;;
  ?) exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

if requested A; then
  echo A
fi
if requested B; then
  echo B
fi
if requested C; then
  echo C
fi
if requested D; then
  echo D
fi
```

you can test it with `./skip-parts.sh -s AC` and similar.  it will react to unknown options and `-s` without an *optarg* with messages similar to

```
./skip-parts.sh: illegal option -- x
./skip-parts.sh: option requires an argument -- s
```

if you don't like the default error messages, you can silence them by prepending the first argument to getopts(1) with a colon, and give your own in the `?` case (the *option requires an argument* case is signalled by setting *optname* to colon... but you said you've read the docs already).